# Trimming String in Java

Tags: java

I need to perform some operation on string.

Scenario is I need to compare that a[i] = b[i].

now say a[i] = Set Temperature

Now since a[i] contains the word Temperature, b[i] will be set to "Set Temerature (C)". (This is the business rule).

In this case a[i] will not be equal to b[i].

For my testing purpose how can trim value of b[i] to set to Set Temprature?

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`String#contains`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) instead.

```
String first = "Set Temperature";
String second = "Set Temperature (C)";

if(second.contains(first)) {
    // logic
}
```

Ordering is important - note that if you reverse the call between first and second, it will fail, since first does not contain any characters such as `" (C)"`.

Answer (score 0):

Use String.contains(). See the java docs

[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)

Comment: Hey Brendan, just a tip. Don't worry about being first. Just focus on writing *good* answers. I remember it took me awhile to get over trying to be first before I discovered I could add a late answer and just simply make mine more detailed than the others. :)  Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I got your question right.

But based on what I understood - instead of checking for equality you can check

if(b[i].startsWith(a[i])

Comment: Is there an implicit guarantee that the data will always be at the front?